# Terminating punctuation in table entries

Tags: punctuation, technical

I always get a little flustered by the question of how to punctuate the end of each of my table entries, where the table is part of a longer document primarily composed of traditional sentences but that has other tables, as well. Consider a typical table of mine, where column 1 has very brief entries (for instance, a name or an ID); column 2 has description cells, where at least one of the entries is long enough to require a period; column 3 cells are populated with data type (for instance, long, int, string, and so forth); and column 4 has various cells each of which simply reads "optional" or "mandatory."

Without column 2, there would be no reason to add a final period to the end of any cell, but I can't just get rid of column 2, after all. There is a general principle of consistency in tables, but if I'm highly consistent, the table looks ridiculous with all of those periods. My gut tells me to be reasonable and include final periods only in column 2. That always strikes me as the least of all evils and yet not a perfect answer. What do you people think?

Comment: Tables typically do not have punctuation at the end of a number or term or phrase. Period, end of story. Periods would only be used if your table has full sentences. This is not about length.

Comment: It might help if you gave some actual examples. For instance, the column 2 entry that has a period as well as another one (that doesn't) for comparison.

Comment: OP here. (Do we say that in this forum?) OK, you guys convinced me that in general, even with long text in a cell, the terminating punctuation should be avoided, but what about cases where the cell has several actual sentences in? Suppose it's a "Notes" cell that talks about specific examples. If there are several complete sentences in one cell, you obviously need to punctuate those sentences, which leads to two questions: 1. Punctuate the last sentence? (I'm thinking yes.) 2. Does this affect whether or not to punctuate other cells in that column or even in other columns?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image]The table in the link illustrates my opinion. Only full sentences need periods. Nothing else does. There is no punctuation at the end of the entries that are not full sentences except for the title and very long entries. However, even a long entry that is not a sentence needn't have a period. That is a style choice. And entries can start with a dash or a bullet point, if required.

[Table Box-5](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK215939/)

Comment: @Ash , I suspect that the title ending in a period is a typo.

Comment: I understand your rule. Do you have a source for it besides deriving it from an existing table that NIH published? Do you have a source in a style manual?

Comment: @Ash There may or may not be a formal reason. Ask the NHS. Generally, though, that would be my rule. It is a rule, not a sweeping statement. Also, the NHS has all their titles followed by a period. That is their style sheet.  I would capitalize a title and not use periods.

Comment: @user6267463 Oh, please, this is an example of usage. And my advice is sound. What I have said is generally followed. There is no end punctuation in tables in English  unless it's a full sentence: Subject + predicate. That is the only case where a period is warranted. Semi-colons never, commas never, in lists  in cells. Style sheets (not manuals) are written by organizations or people.

Comment: Lambie, fair enough, but how do you decide when to use "Oh please," (sigh), or 2x (sigh) to chastise others on here? Is there a general rule of usage for that, too?

Comment: @user6267463 [sigh] is not chastisement, it's desperation.  "Oh please" is also not chastisement, it's frustration.

Comment: I voted for Lambie's answer.  It has the advantages of being simple, easy to implement, and not requiring ugly punctuation. Queue fight tournament sequence from "Karate Kid" that starts with "You're the Best" in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I agree and disagree with Lambie's comment, table entries just don't have terminal punctuation at all in my experience, not number terms, not short descriptive notes and not even full sentences. Excessive punctuation simply doesn't have a place in tables, they should contain completely necessary data only.

Comment: Full sentences would require periods. Long and long-ish phrases might have an en-dash at the beginning. Otherwise, no punctuation. See for yourself here, for example: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK215939/ That is a complex table, but the sentences have periods.

Comment: @Lambie I'd only use a period to delineate multiple sentences within a single cell not to terminate a cell entry. The tables you've linked actually appear rather hit-and-miss in their application of punctuation, if I'm reading what you wanted to point me at.

Comment: If you have seven entries in a cell, beginning with dashes or bullets, I would use periods at the end if they are complete sentences. Table 5-B has one exception, the Title. Otherwise, it shows what I mean. The same goes for PPTs: a complete sentence takes a period, otherwise, no periods and caps at the beginning.

Comment: @Lambie the "Effectiveness" column of Table B-3 uses periods even for phrases, which appears to also counter what you are suggesting.

Comment: .delineate multiple sentences? **delineate**? terminal punctuation??

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple.

Keep only that data which is absolutely essential and expected when you do a CRUD operation. Don't get carried away(we all do). A table should hold data we *need*. Nothing else.